# Updating play framework project to Java 11 and cannot find correct dependency versions

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka, java-11

Updating an existing maven project from Java 8 to 11, and I'm struggling to find the right combination of dependency and plugin versions.
One of the modules uses the play framework, with its associated dependencies, here's what they are set to now:

```
java: 11.0.5                    
scala: 2.12.8                   
sbt: 0.13.17                            
sbt-compiler-maven-plugin: 1.0.0        
sbtrun-maven-plugin: 1.0.1          
play: 2.6.21                    
play2-maven-plugin: 1.0.0-rc5
play2-provider-play26: 1.0.0-rc5        
akka: 2.5.27
```

Which is giving me the following build error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin:play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-rc5:enhance (default-play2-enhance) on project services: Execution default-play2-enhance of goal com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin:play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-rc5:enhance failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin:play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-rc5:enhance: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps scala.Predef$.byteArrayOps(byte[])'
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    extension>com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin:play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-rc5
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
...
...
...
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Note: I am hoping to keep akka to version 2.5.x, as 2.6.x requires a lot of code changes, but will go to a higher version if necessary

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <packaging>play2</packaging>
    <name>name</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>typesafe</id>
            <url>http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play_2.12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-test_2.12</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-java_2.12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
          <artifactId>akka-stream_2.12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- Play source directory -->
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/app</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/conf</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/public</directory>
                <targetPath>public</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/target/sbt/web/public/main</directory>
                <targetPath>public</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>play2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-rc5</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainLang>java</mainLang>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>play2-provider-play27</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-rc5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-play2-enhance</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>dist</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.sbt-compiler-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>sbt-compiler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.sbtrun-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>sbtrun-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-assets</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>web-assets:assets</args>
                            <jvmArgs>-Dscala.version=2.12.8</jvmArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                    <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- &lt;!&ndash; These empty tags keep IntelliJ quiet &ndash;&gt; -->
                    <name />
                    <regex />
                    <source />
                    <value />
                    <fileSet />
                    <artifacts>
                        <artifact>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/service-${project.version}-dist.zip</file>
                            <type>zip</type>
                            <classifier>dist</classifier>
                        </artifact>
                    </artifacts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>eclipse</id> <!-- for M2Eclipse only -->

            <build>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/target-eclipse</directory>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipMain>true</skipMain>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                            <source>11</source>
                            <target>11</target>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-compile</id>
                                <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                <goals><goal>testCompile</goal></goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Edit:
Updated SBT and Scala version, added redacted pom

Answer (score 2):

As per scala documentation
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Your SBT version is not compatible with Java 11. I would recommend upgrading to sbt.version=1.2.3

Akka version you are using should be good if you don't want to upgrade to higher.

**Update:**

I can see you updated sbt version to 0.13.17 and you tried with higher, but you should forget that sbt 0.13 and stick with sbt 1.x since sbt 0.13 is using scala 2.10, and sbt 1.x scala 2.12.

I've also noticed that you don't have version tag for maven-compiler-plugin. If you are using maven 3, it should fail to build because of missing this tag, and since it's not, I guess you are using maven 2 which should be upgraded. Also you should add  3.8.0 version tag to maven-compiler-plugin.

Check [this guide](https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/) to see how to properly configure this plugin for java 11. You should also check other instructions to see if everything is properly configured.

Comment: thanks for the response, sorry the original question had a typo for the SBT version, I had tried it already with the JDK 11 recommended versions of 0.13.17 and 1.1.0 (and also now 1.2.3) but still no luck

Comment: I'm suspecting your problem is related to your maven configuration. Can you post your maven configuration please?